# C++ TDD UnitTest++ compiler error

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm trying to compile (`g++ factorial.cpp -o factorial -lUnitTest++`), but do not understand what to implement. Does anyone have idea what can be done here?

Thank you

```
#include <cmath>
#include <unittest++/UnitTest++.h>

unsigned factorial(unsigned n);

SUITE(describe_factorial)
{
    TEST(factorial_of_zero_should_be_1)
    {
        CHECK_EQUAL(1, factorial(0));
    }
    TEST(factorial_of_should_be_24)
    {
        CHECK_EQUAL(24, factorial(4));
    }
}

int main()
{
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error you are receiving?

Comment: Seems highly likely that you need to implement `factorial`. Isn't that the point of the assignment?

Comment: Post error you are getting while compiling this code

Comment: Error:

'/tmp/ccgaR3cs.o: In Funktion'
`Suitedescribe_factorial::Testfactorial_of_zero_should_be_1::RunImpl() const':
factorial.cpp:(.text+0x2f): Nicht definierter Verweis auf
`factorial(unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccgaR3cs.o: In Funktion `Suitedescribe_factorial::Testfactorial_of_should_be_24::RunImpl() const':
factorial.cpp:(.text+0xeb): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `factorial(unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: As @rici mentioned, you need to define `factorial`. (That's literally what your error message is telling you.)